# Как подгружать табы из календаря?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно реализовать табы, в котором каждый отдельный таб это дата календаря. Табы скроллятся вправо. Я так понимаю, что стандартный TabHost не поможет. Также наверняка потребуется подгрузка/выгрузка элементов. Посоветуйте методы реализации и куда "копать".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь можно использовать горизонтальный список (`ListView`), адаптер которого будет формировать даты.
 Для отображения результата ниже самого горизонтального списка - фрагмент, в который по клику на айтеме списка будет отправляться информация, связанная с текущей позицией в списке.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую горизонтальный `RecyclerView` для этих целей, изначально допустим кладем в него на один месяц данные, ставим на на него `ScrollListener`, как только скроллим, допустим до dates.size() - 10, генерируем еще один месяц и добавляем в него.

Comment: Попытаюсь реализовать этот способ.

Comment: @P.Dm Только `RecyclerView` излишен по функциональности и одновременно более сложен в реализации для такой задачи. Здесь уместнее `ListView`

Comment: @pavlofff и в чем же сложность состоит?

Comment: Основновная сложность состоит в том, что некоторые разработчики склонны к модным влияниям в ущерб принципа разумной достаточности. Излишен, потому что `LayoutManager` здесь не нужен, но будет создан. Ни один метод, отличающий `RecyclerView` от  `ListView` не будет использован, но будет загружен в память (и прочее). Одновременно, нужные в решении этой задачи слушатель кликов по айтему и, наиболее очевидно, `CursorAdapter` отсутствуют в `RecyclerView` и их придется писать самостоятельно, еще увеличивая ненужный для решения код.